# Apply custom theme/code to CKAN extension

Tags: python, jinja2, ckan

I hope I can explain myself clearly. I have a CKAN instance which has a custom theme. This theme is implemented as a custom extension and is completely functional. Now I want to add an output info from another extension to this custom template.

I know how to extend with `{% extends %}` from default template and how `{% block %}` works too. But I don't know how to manage my custom extension output to put it on my custom template (from a distinct custom extension).

For example I have `custom_search_form.html`:

```
{% extends 'snippets/search_form.html' %}
  ...      

  {% if ok %}
        my code
  {% endif %}

  ...
{% endblock %}
```

If this is my custom template (and it's working), I want now to move that 'if' block to my new extension. What I should add here or how I refer from this to my new code? I don't know If this is even possible.

If the question is not enough clear please tell me and I'll try to clarify. Many many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to use `{% extends '...' %}` to override one plugin's templates in a second plugin. Simply use the path of the original template (without the prefix for the template directory) when extending it. For example, if your theme has a template

```
/path/to/your/theme/ckanext/my_custom_theme/public/templates/my_custom_theme/some_snippet.html
```

then you can extend it in your extension using

```
{% extends 'my_custom_theme/some_snippet.hml' %}
```

As shown above, extensions should put new templates in a separate subdirectory to avoid name clashes.

The only thing that you need to keep in mind is the order in which the plugins are listed in your `production.ini`: plugins listed earlier can extend those listed later, but not vice versa.

Since you want to override your theme from your extension, this means that you need to list the extension first:

```
ckan.plugins = ... my_custom_extension ... my_custom_theme ...
```

Comment: I've already solve my problem and it was exactly like you said. At first I didn't use the same path so it didn't work. I don't know how but I managed to get to that point. I suppose it was just trying everything.
Anyway, I didn't know that rule for extensions' order in `production.ini` so thank you so much for clarify it too.

Comment: @yeuk0 @florian-brucker

So if extension file path is:

`/ckan/ckanext-extension/ckanext/extension/templates/snippets/extension_list.html`

Should look like `{% extends 'snippets/extenison_list.html' %}` path

and where store file in my template?

Comment: @neuroine If I didn't misunderstand you, that should work fine. You must always include the path from `template` without the first slash just as you wrote so that should do the thing.